# What does "it deltas memory" mean in the context of Terracotta?

Tags: java, distributed-caching, terracotta

I am reading the book Spring Recipes. I am not able to comprehend certain things said about terracota.

The following is a paragraph from the book

> Terracotta is different than most clustered caches today because it has no visible API, and because
>   it’s far more efficient in conveying the changed state to nodes across the cluster. Most systems use some
>   sort of Java serialization or broadcast mechanism, wherein each other node is given the entire object, or
>   object graph, that’s changed, regardless of whether they even they need to be aware of the new state.
>   Terracotta does it differently: **it deltas the memory of the object graphs itself and synchronizes other
>   nodes in the cluster as they need a consistent view of the object state**. Succinctly, it can do something
>   tantamount to transmitting just one updated variable in an object, and not the entire object.

I can understand that it does not use anything like serialization to transmit objects across cluster, but what does "**it deltas memory**" mean ?

Comment: Hope this helps : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAZnsofBV-I

Comment: I have seen that video. It does not answer my question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding

Comment: [Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @Jarrod - The OP isn't asking to explain the entire framework (unlike the question's title implies), simply clarification on a certain sentence of a book. @ cmv - It would be best to change your question's title to something more specific like "What does it mean to delta memory of an object graph?". As it stands, your question's title is far too generic for what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As axtavt has commented, a [Delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) is essentially the difference between two instances of an object.

> ... it deltas the memory of the object graphs ...

Can be restated in simpler terms like...

> It determines the difference between the object instances

What the paragraph is essentially saying is...

Other caching frameworks/technologies synchronize the state of objects across multiple nodes in a cluster by sending messages between nodes that contain every piece of information about each instance, even data that hasn't changed. Terracotta handles this more efficiently by only sending the information which has changed to synchronize the objects.

Think of this like an SVN commit. When you commit a file to an SVN repo, your computer doesn't send the entire file to the server, it only sends a diff (or delta) to synchronize the repository version of the file with your local copy.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It worth mentioning that the book is deprecated and isn't the way that most people use Terracotta nowadays (people use express mode, which is serialization-based for "user-types").

Anyways, trying to answer your question: Terracotta instruments your classes so all the necessary hooks around field mutation and locking are there, so that changes done (under proper locking) will be the ones propagated to, first, the L2 (aka Terracotta server); second, to nodes trying to read these fields.

I hope this (very quick and short) answer does slightly answer your question.